# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

¿Alguien sabe como puedo puedo hacer para que el mysqli_fetch_array me pueda leer **3 parámetros**?

```
$registros = 1; //registros por página
$sql = "SELECT * FROM base1";
$result = mysqli_query($conec, $sql);
$reg_total = @mysqli_num_rows($result);

//total de páginas
$pag = ceil($reg_total / $registros);

@mysqli_free_result($result);

if (!isset($_GET['screen']))
$screen = 0;
$position = 0;

$inici = $screen * $registros;
//consulta
$sql = "SELECT * FROM base1 order by ID ASC LIMIT ".$position.",".$registros;
//query
$result = mysqli_query($conec, $sql);
$rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);

//mostrar registros
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$titol = mysqli_fetch_row($result,$i,1);
$video = mysqli_fetch_array($result,$i,2);
echo ("<h1> $titol </h1>");

echo ("<video width='600px' height='400px' controls>
  <source src='$video' type='video/mp4'>
</viedo>");
}


//anterior, numero, siguiente
echo '<p><hr></p>
<div style="widht:100%; text-align:center;">';

//registro anterior
if ($position >= 1) {
$url = "cap.php?screen=" .($position-1);
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Anterior</a>\n";
}

//mostrar registro actual
echo '<strong>'.($position+1).' de '.$pag.' <strong>';

//siguiente registro
if ($position < ($pag-1)) {
$url = "cap.php?screen=" . ($position+1);
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Siguiente</a>\n";
} 
echo '</div>';

?>
```

---

Lo que quiero hacer es un paginado de solo 1 registro por página

```
$registros = 1; //registros por página
$sql = "SELECT * FROM base1";
$result = mysqli_query($conec, $sql);
$reg_total = @mysqli_num_rows($result);

//total de páginas
$pag = ceil($reg_total / $registros);

@mysqli_free_result($result);

if (!isset($_GET['screen']))
$screen = 0;
$position = 0;

$inici = $screen * $registros;
//consulta
$sql = "SELECT * FROM base1 order by ID ASC LIMIT ".$position.",".$registros;
//query
$result = mysqli_query($conec, $sql);
$rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);

//mostrar registros
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
$titol = mysqli_fetch_row($result,$i,1);
$video = mysqli_fetch_array($result,$i,2);
echo ("<h1> $titol </h1>");

echo ("<video width='600px' height='400px' controls>
      <source src='$video' type='video/mp4'>
    </viedo>");
}


//anterior, numero, siguiente
echo '<p><hr></p>
<div style="widht:100%; text-align:center;">';

//registro anterior
if ($position >= 1) {
$url = "cap.php?screen=" .($position-1);
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Anterior</a>\n";
}

//mostrar registro actual
echo '<strong>'.($position+1).' de '.$pag.' <strong>';

//siguiente registro
if ($position < ($pag-1)) {
$url = "cap.php?screen=" . ($position+1);
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Siguiente</a>\n";
}
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: puedes añadir que consulta estas haciendo a la base de datos?

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/110565)

Answer (score 1):

No está muy claro lo que intentas hacer, pero posiblemente lo que quieres es obtener los elementos de tu consulta.

Primero tienes que tener en cuenta que [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

> Retorna un array de strings que corresponde a la fila obtenida o NULL
>   si no hay más filas en el resultset.

y tiene como máximo dos parámetros:

> **result**
>
> Sólo estilo por procedimientos: Un conjunto de identificadores de resultados devuelto por `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` o
>   `mysqli_use_result()`.
>
> **resulttype**
>
> Este parámetro opcional es una constante que indica qué tipo de array debiera generarse con la información de la fila actual. Los
>   valores posibles para este parámetro son las constantes `MYSQLI_ASSOC`,
>   `MYSQLI_NUM`, o `MYSQLI_BOTH`.
>
> Al emplear la constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` esta función se comportará de manera idéntica a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, mientras que con `MYSQLI_NUM` se
>   comportará exactamente igual que la función `mysqli_fetch_row()`. La
>   última opción `MYSQLI_BOTH` creará un único array con los atributos de
>   ambas dos.

Por lo tanto, lo que estas intentando hacer no es correcto.

Si lo que deseas es obtener los resultados de tu consulta haz esto:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    

$titol = rows[0]; // la primera fila de tu consulta
$video = rows[1]; // la segunda fila de tu consulta

echo ("<h1> $titol </h1>");
echo ("<video width='600px' height='400px' control
<source src='$video' type='video/mp4'>
</video>");
```